# Adding a Basic Java Program into Website

Tags: java, javascript, html, image

Firstly I am no longer a student and doing this for other purposes, so don't hold back on the help ;)

I want to incorporate a simple program into my webpage. I want 4 buttons labelled right arm, left arm, activate voice and walk forward. There will be a box above these buttons showing an image of a robot and as the buttons are pressed by the user I want a different image to be loaded in the box.

So if the right arm button is pressed the image with the robot raising its right arm will need to be displayed.

So basically all I want the buttons to do is to load the image that belongs to each one. I am assuming java is the best choice? I have the open source Java package, would I need any other software when it comes to embedding it into a webpage? My webpage is done on dreamweaver and I am pretty good with html. Would appreciate it if someone could point me to the right direction.....Thanks

Comment: I would suggest that JavaScript is a much better choice.  Java seems like overkill for an application that does nothing more than show/hide images in a web browser.

Comment: Are you confusing Java with Javascript perchance? You do know the difference, right?

Comment: I hope you are not thinking of using Applets (tech from a past century ;))

Comment: Added the [tag:JavaScript] tag (probably the way this should be done) but left the Java tag (until the OP clarifies).

Comment: *"I am no longer a student"*  Congratulations, perhaps it is a good time to change your Nic./user name.

Comment: Yes JavaScript is what I need, never knew you could change user names I will do that ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use Java for this.  Use JavaScript.  Something like this:

HTML:

```
<img src="one.jpg" id="firstImage" />
<img src="two.jpg" id="secondImage" />

​<button id="doSomething">Do Something</button>
<button id="doSomethingElse">​Do Something Else</button>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```
​img {
    display: none;
}​
```

JavaScript:

```
var hideImages = function() {
    $('#firstImage').hide();
    $('#secondImage').hide();
};

$('#doSomething').click(function() {
    hideImages();
    $('#firstImage').show();
});

$('#doSomething').click(function() {
    hideImages();
    $('#secondImage').show();
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

What this essentially does is initially display no images, just buttons.  Then as each button is clicked, the corresponding image is displayed.  (And all other images are first hidden, since previous button clicks would have displayed previous images.)

This is an overly simple proof of concept, of course.  At the very least you'll want to use better variable names :)  This just demonstrates the idea of how you'd show/hide images in JavaScript in response to button clicks.  (This also assumes the use of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), which is a safe assumption these days.  The easiest way to use that is to refer to [a CDN link](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery) in your page, using a standard [HTML `script` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html).)  You can [see this code in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/7sAGB/) (though the images are broken, of course.)

If there are a lot of buttons and a lot of images, you may be able to re-factor the code to be less repetitive as well.  Maybe store the images in an array and have a single button click handler which can associate the sending button with the correct array element, etc.  That's up to you.

Comment: @RobW: A fair point.  I've updated the answer with a short statement and a couple of links that should at least set him in the right direction (and give him some terms to Google if he gets lost.)

Comment: I was more thinking about showing the full code (including relevant `<script>` tags) which can be copy-pasted for a stand-alone test case. A [reference to JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) might also be useful here ;)

Comment: Thankyou david that does make sense, So to use javascript I can just insert it into the html using dreamweaver, like this for e.g. <script type="text/javascript"> and start coding? Full code would really help!

Comment: @Student: I'm on a mobile device now, so I can only be so helpful :)  A Google search for "how to use JavaScript" has helpful links.  Essentially, you have two ways.  Both of which use the "script" HTML tag.  On references a file of JavaScript code (a single script tag with a src attribute and a closing tag).  The other is to write the code within the script tag and then close the tag.

Comment: @Student: Remember that JavaScript is executed in the browser when the page is rendered, not on the server.  So mixing it with any server-side functionality requires considerably more knowledge of web architecture and development.

Comment: Yh thanks I did some searching and understand it better now. In the above code example you gave under the JavaScript header, is that code creating the buttons as-well?

Comment: Rob W if I did have a test case ready code that I could edit and change and learn from, that would be very helpful.

Comment: @Student: The HTML code creates the image references and the buttons, the CSS code styles them (in this case hides the images initially), the JavaScript code responds to events (in this case button click events, where it then re-styles the images to no longer be hidden).

Comment: Sorry I have just realized your link to the code in action. I think I can go ahead and start this right, thank you David you did do a lot using a mobile device!

Comment: Sorry one more question, how would I hot-link the jQuery CDN Link? Would this be done within the JavaScript?

Comment: @Student: Hot-linking a CDN-hosted JavaScript file (or linking to any JavaScript file) would be its own `script` tag in the page's header.  The CDN URL would be the `src` attribute of the `script` tag.  Something like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I've implemented this onto my webpage and it's working ;) I just wanted to make minor changes to the layout, I want the 4 buttons to be positioned on top of each other. I also need to have 1 picture box were the image changes after clicking the buttons rather than having separate pictures for each one. I am trying to use Google to find out how to do this but have hit a wall...

Comment: @Student: For positioning the elements, you'll want to look into CSS.  There are a number of tutorials and books out there.  If you want to have a single `img` element, you'd just have to change the `src` attribute on that element.  The jQuery documentation should have information on how to do that.  Specifically here: http://api.jquery.com/attr/  Keep in mind, however, that from the user's perspective there's no difference.  Whether you swap out images or alter the `src` attribute on an image, the effect is the same.

Comment: Been trying for a while and was not able to do it, I just need one image box that will refresh it's image when the buttons are pressed.....can someone provide me with a sample code for that please

Comment: When I implement everything on the webpage I only see the buttons and when I press them the image does not show up?

Comment: @Student: That probably qualifies for a new Stack Overflow question.  Go ahead and ask one in which you show your code, perhaps even link to a demonstration of it (a public server or jsfiddle), and explain what the problem is.

Comment: @Student: That's still worth a new question, as long comment threads like this one aren't very productive.  You'll want to focus on the difference between the working version and the non-working version, as that difference should find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are many technologies that could help you: javascript is one of them and it would be much simpler than using Java for such simple thing.  You can use Java applet if you really want to use Java for that project.